# grails find first

Tags: grails

I know this is simple question but taking more time

How to find first record from table in grails .

I need to get only the first record with out knowing the id number .

Is there any method like find :first in grails ?

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have to define by what measure this record is supposed to be the "first".

Assuming that you mean the record with the earliest creation timestamp, the easiest and most robust approach would be to add a `dateCreated` property to your domain class and then querying for the entity with the lowest such date. In fact you don't even have to set the creation date manually, because Grails does this for you (as long as you name the property `dateCreated`) - see [Automatic timestamping](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.1/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) in the Grails Documentation.

The HQL query would be something like:

```
def firstObject = YourClass.find("FROM YourClass ORDER BY dateCreated")
```

Comment: yeah.I need just to fetch the first record in db irrespective of any timestamp. because my timestamp will always change when edited . cant we get with out timestamp ?
Thanks Daniel.

Comment: "because my timestamp will always change when edited" -> If you use Grails' automatic timestamping, there is a difference between `dateCreated` (set once upon insert and not changed thereafter) and `lastUpdated` (updated upon each update/change).

Comment: If your id is numeric and auto incremented in strictly ascending order, you could of course just `ORDER BY id`

Answer (score 14):

Updating to Grails 2.1.1 or later adds two new methods (first and last) for GORM to address this needed feature.

From the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/first.html):

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Integer age
}

// retrieve the first person ordered by the identifier
def p = Person.first()
// retrieve the first person ordered by the lastName property
p = Person.first(sort: 'lastName')

// retrieve the first person ordered by the lastName property
p = Person.first('lastName')
```

Comment: Most of these convenience methods are not useful to me since it's never obvious how I would specify a simple where clause.  For example, if I wanted to find the last Order a person made, I can't simply do Order.first([sort: 'orderDateTime', order: 'desc']) since I don't have a separate order table for each user in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Check out hibernate criteria and projections, e.g:

```
def location = Location.createCriteria()
def firstRecord = location.list{
    maxResults(1)
    order("id","asc")//assuming auto increment just to make sure 
}[0]
```

http://grails.org/doc/1.0.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Answer (score 1):

If timestamp doesn't matter, you could try if Daniel's answer without ORDER BY works, i.e.

```
def firstObject = YourClass.find("FROM YourClass")
```

Comment: I would rather not rely on the assumption, that this returns the object inserted first. AFAIK, this is an implementation detail of the DBMS and depending on the DBMS you use may not hold true. Same as with `SELECT * FROM xyz LIMIT 1` in plain SQL.

Comment: As for MySQL, I just found this thread in the forum: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,239471,239471 Conclusion: Due to the implementation of the engine, the default order MAY be the insert order (at least for MyISAM), but this is definitely nothing to rely on! I suppose the same holds for other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grails findBy methods to return the first result of a query.

-> From the [1.3.7 docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html)

> findBy*
>
> Purpose
>
> Dynamic method that uses the properties of the domain class to allow
>   the creation of Grails query method expressions that return the first
>   result of the query

-> from the [latest docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html)

> findBy* Purpose
>
> Dynamic method that uses the properties of the domain class to execute
>   a query returning the first matching result.